# WARNING: 997: Failure to setup sound, err = -50

Tags: xcode, ios9

i'm getting this message WARNING: 997: Failure to setup sound, err = -50 when I attempt to play a sound file. The sound plays but I don't understand the message.
This is new to iOS 9 and xcode 7
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I see this only in the simulator when I do `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`.  Are you getting it on a device?  If not, I think it can be ignored (in my case, the sim has no vibrator).

Answer (score 4):

Its happened because you have this line :

```
 AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

You need to disable it.

Good luck!

Comment: So, does that mean I have to eliminate vibration?  Or, is there another new method?  Thanks for the help

Comment: I think it's simply because the simulator has no way of simulating vibrations. You just have to wrap that line of code around a device check to see if it's on a physical device that's an iPhone, which is the only device that has vibration capabilities.